# Switch current tag to another

Tags: sublimetext2

I have a tag like

```
<p>this is a pa|ragraph</p>
```

I want to press a button and change p to another tag.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the Emmet(Previously ZenCoding) plugin. It has a shortcut <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>(For Mac, for other OSes, it should be Ctrl instead of Super) for this.

```
{
    "keys": [
        "super+shift+k"
    ], 
    "command": "rename_tag", 
    "context": [
        {
            "key": "emmet_action_enabled.rename_tag"
        }
    ]
},
```

Just highlight the tag, press that combo and both opening and closing tags will be selected simultaneously. So you can then just type the new tag.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can just simply replace the tag, but Jquery has a function call ".replaceWith", you can simply use this to do something like this.

```
<p id="someID">Some text goes here</p>
```

then in Javascript

```
var content = $('#someID').html();
$('#someID').replaceWith('<h2 id="someID">' + content + '</h2>');
```